# Very short math question regarding mirroring?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

In what lines of the plane Cw is $x^2+ y^2=4$ mirrored using the function $w=1/z$.
Now, this is a complicated question and I have no idea how to do this..can you please help me?

Comment: Please provide context, or in some other way clarify the question. (What is the plance Cw for instance? Does it somehow have to do with $w$?)

Comment: If this were a complex-numbers problem, I'd say $z=x+iy$, so $x^2+y^2=4$ is $|z|^2=4$, so $|w|^2=1/4$, so if $w=u+iv$ then the mirrored image is $u^2+v^2=1/4$. But it says it's a calculus problem, so I don't know.

Comment: It is complex analysis!

Comment: Then does my comment seem like it might be the answer?

Comment: Your comment is the answer.Thanks Gerry :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson It seems that OP would like you to post this as an answer. Such has the benefit of removing the question from the Unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1):

As it appears that my comment is the answer, I may as well make my comment an answer.

$z=x+iy$, so $x^2+y^2=4$ is $|z|^2=4$, so $|w|^2=1/4$; as $w=u+iv$, the mirrored image is $u^2+v^2=1/4$.